# Passivische Bedeutung?

Tags: german-to-english, passive

> Wandel Passiv in Passiversatz um:
>
> An der Uni soll ein großer Teil des Wissens eigenständig erarbeitet werden.
>
> An der Uni bleibt ein großer Teil des Wissens eigenständig zu erarbeiten.

My teacher taught us ersatz passive very similar to how it is presented [here](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/passiversatz.html). In a test we had, one of my friends reformulated the sentence like above and the teacher told his solution works too.

Why so? Could someone explain why?

Comment: The first sentence doesn't really make sense (and isn't passive), are you sure you copied it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

> An der Uni soll **ein großer Teil des Wissens** eigenständig erarbeitet werden.

That's the passive voice of a modal expression. A typical active voice sentence is:

> An der Uni soll **man einen großen Teil des Wissens** eigenständig erarbeiten.

That method turns the subject of the passive voice sentence *ein großer Teil des Wissens* into the accusative object of the active voice sentences and invents an unpersonal subject *man* on the fly.

---

What your friend did is something different:

> An der Uni bleibt ein großer Teil des Wissens eigenständig zu erarbeiten.

First, you can see that it's not the usual passive voice, as there is not *werden* involved. And neither *sein* so it's not static passive either.

*Sein, werden, …* do you know the third common verb from that group? … Yep, it's *bleiben*. Those are copula verbs. Actually, you can also phrase this with *sein*:

> An der Uni ist ein großer Teil des Wissens eigenständig zu erarbeiten.

(Other matching copula verbs at this place are e.g. *gelten als* or *scheinen*. The copula *werden* doesn't work here for semantic reasons.)

Copula verbs take a predicative complement that explains the subject. That's the trick at this point.  That predicative complement may be an adjective for example:

> An der Uni ist ein großer Teil des Wissens uralt.

As participles can stand in for adjectives, we can put them there as well:

> An der Uni ist ein großer Teil des Wissens widerlegt.

And this is also true for the third participle German has, the Gerundivum. Or rather, its zu-Infinitiv replacement form which is mandatory for predicative use:

> An der Uni ist ein großer Teil des Wissens **zu finden.**

And that **participle of what could be done or has to be done** may be explained further as well:

> An der Uni ist ein großer Teil des Wissens **eigenständig zu erarbeiten.**

The reason why this can stand in for the original sentence is the modal expression in passive voice. As that *Gerundivum* replaces exactly that: a modal expression in passive voice. It tells *what could be done or has to be done*.